# Access iterator in the function object of for_each wth execution policy

Tags: c++, c++17, std, parallel.foreach

Is there any way to access the iterator in order to find the index of the element we are processing when using `std::for_each()` from the algorithm header? This could be useful in cases that execution policy is required.
Consider the following example (mutex and .. removed for simplicity) in the second `std::for_each()` where execution policy `std::par_unseq` is used, `i++` could not be used on pain of undefined behaviour. So is there a way to access the iterator and find the index without having to pair the index to vec2 elements?
Also looking for a general solution for all containers?

```
vector<int> vec1{1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 0, 3, 9};
vector<int> vec2{1, 5, 2, 3};
vector<int> vec3(4), vec4(4);

size_t i = 0;
for_each(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), [&vec1, &vec3, &i](const auto& e) {
    vec3[i++] = vec1[e];
});

for_each(execution::par_unseq, vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), [&vec1, &vec4](const auto& e) {
    vec4[distance(vec2.begin(), current_iterator)] = vec1[e];
});
```

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just use [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)?

Answer (score 0):

std::vector has contiguous memory so you can use pointers(and calculate their difference).

That being said I do not understand your original problem or motivation so you may want to consider recreating this question with more details or editing it.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you do not want to use `size_t i = 0;` kind of iterator for obvious reasons and I would also not recommend that. Look for Iterator validity section of [distance](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/distance/) before using it with any container.

When you use `for_each` with `std::par_unseq` then it will be totally random. In fact in my test your first loop is also copying in random order. `{4,0,5,6}` instead of `{1,4,5,6}`.

I would suggest you to use a sequential container and divide it to ranges so different ranges can be parallelized sequentially or design your own non-sequential container which can be divided with some logic and used in parallel.